# Why does the EventListener work only the first time?

Tags: java, android-studio, calculator, event-listener

I use this java code in order to code an **Android RPN calculator**.

Now I'm in the stage where clicking on a  button triggers the value of the button to be displayed in a **TextView** field (or at least to display something with `Toast.makeText`) but unfortunately it works only for the first buttonclick.

The **next events** are ignored (no message via Toast and no change in the textview fiels). Do you have any idea why?

> MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn0:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("0");
            Toast.makeText( this, "btn0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.btn1:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("1");
            Toast.makeText( this, "btn0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("2");
            Toast.makeText( this, "btn0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("3");
            break;
        case R.id.btn4:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("4");
            break;
        case R.id.btn5:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("5");
            break;
        case R.id.btn6:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("6");
            break;
        case R.id.btn7:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("7");
            break;
        case R.id.btn8:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("8");
            break;
        case R.id.btn9:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.append("9");
            break;


        case R.id.Plus:

            break;
        case R.id.Minus:

            break;
        case R.id.Power:

            break;
        case R.id.Root:

            break;

        case R.id.MPlus:

            break;
        case R.id.MMinus:

            break;
        case R.id.AC:
            stackedit0 = findViewById(R.id.stackedit0);
            stackedit0.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.MRC:

            break;



    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` from your `onClick()` method.